# Create Rounded Toggle Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, rounded-corners, togglebutton

I want to create ToggleButton which have CornerRadius DependencyProperty that bound to it's Borders' CornerRadius in standard template. My steps:

In Blend I just dropped ToggleButton on the MainWindow then using context menu selected "Make Into UserControl". In Code behind I created my DependencyProperty CornerRadius:

```
public partial class RoundedToggleButton : UserControl
{
    public RoundedToggleButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    [Category("Appearance")]
    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(RoundedToggleButton), new PropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius()));
}
```

Then I created Template using "Edit Template -> Edit a copy.." and put it in the same place with my UserControl definition and added template binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SqlDeploymentTool.RoundedToggleButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SqlDeploymentTool"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="19.96"
         d:DesignWidth="76.257"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                               StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                               StrokeThickness="1" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383" />
    <Style x:Key="RoundedToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding local:RoundedToggleButton.CornerRadius}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Focusable="False"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
                  Content="ToggleButton"
                  Style="{DynamicResource RoundedToggleButtonStyle}" />

</Grid>
```

In Property Window I get the CornerRadius Property but it's not affected to the button's border. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, making a custom control instead of a UserControl would have been more simple and straight-forward than this.

Create a class named `RoundedToggleButton` that inherits from `ToggleButton` and include your `CornerRadius` DependencyProperty on it. And then create a default Style (with no `x:Key`, just the `TargetType`) similar to the one you have there, but changing all the TargetTypes to `RoundedToggleButton` instead of `ToggleButton`.

In that case, this line...

```
CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding local:RoundedToggleButton.CornerRadius}"
```

... Would be simply:

```
CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
```

And most important, it'd work!

BUT since you've already gone all the way to create the UserControl, simply change that line for:

```
CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                       AncestorType={x:Type local:RoundedToggleButton}}}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! This really helps)) Now it works like a charm))

Comment: You're welcome! :) But really, give the custom control idea a thought... With your current approach, you'll have to expose new DependencyProperties for each property of the internal `ToggleButton` you want to modify. The text on it, for instance... Right now it's stuck as "ToggleButton" because that's the `Content` you set to it in your `UserControl`, and you won't be able to change it from your view's XAML.

Comment: Of course first approach is best for my situation. I already created my RoundedToggleButton as CustomControl, This is exactly what I wanted. 
Thanks again for your help!!!